Azure Devops 2022 Build Pipeline folder view missing
We switched to Azure Devops 2022 on-premise. We have been on version 2019.
The old version gave us the possiblity to manager our buildpipelines in a folder structure in the Browser in the pipeline section.
I hope i describe it understandable.
Now we are missing this view. I cant see any option, to show this folder structure in the browser again.
if i save a build, i could choose a different path then the root path "\" to store the build in. so i guess there shoul be folders somewhere. Why should they show this dialogue otherwise.
Is there something which has to be configured by the admin to show this view of the folderstructure where the builds were organized in before?
thanks for any advice

In Azure DevOps Server 2022, the Pipeline Folder view has been moved to the Pipelines -> All tab. You can refer to my answer and check if you can find the folder view in the Pipelines All tab.

When we use Azure DevOps server 2019, we can directly see the folder icon in the  Build tab.
For example:

In Azure DevOps Server 2022, the Pipeline Folder view has been moved to the Pipelines -> All tab.

You can check if you can see the Pipeline folder view in the Pipelines -> All tab.

o man, i think i have to get more coffee, im blind. thank you so much, i really didnt see that
